# React limit access to specific users

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework

I'm building an App using react and django as backend.
I have JWT authentication set up and working. But I am wondering if it is safe to include menu items and logic of views that will be displayed only to specific users and will include sensitive information. Of course these views will only be visible to the relevant users.
My question is if it possible for someone to extract the info from the react build? And if so, what is the best practice to avoid such situation?

Comment: Why does the private data stay in the react build? Don't you fetch it from a server where authorisation is required?

Comment: I do fetch it from the server. I am referring to the information included in view, such as titles and menu items which should not be visible to everyone.

Comment: Ok but it doesn't contain anything sensitive then. You're not going to render it in the browser anyway - so the user isn't going to see any non-working view elements. If you're for some reason worried that people could see how it would look like - which isn't a privacy concern as there's no sensitive data there - you can have another react app which is only served to authenticaed users, like trixn answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript code should not contain sensitive information. Such information should be dynamically fetched and checking permissions on a per request basis when the screen is actually rendered that needs to display it.

If you even want to hide certain screens so that users can't see certain features on your app that are not available to them you either need to bundle those screens into another app and serve that on another url or you can dynamically fetch javascript containing these views.

Usually this is not worth the effort as you should concentrate on correctly checking permissions for your api.

**EDIT**:

> Assuming i'd like to dynamically fetch the JS with the sensitive views and add those to my app, how do i do that?

I assume you are using webpack 2 for bundling your react app? Then you need to use [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) for the parts that need to be dynamically loaded. Then in django you need a custom view that serves your static files and checks for permission to access this part of your react app when it is requested.

[This tutorial](https://codeburst.io/how-to-lazy-load-features-using-react-and-webpack-557f559ccde7) explains how to lazy load components using webpack 2.

Comment: Assuming i'd like to dynamically fetch the JS with the sensitive views and add those to my app, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you encode user roles in the JWT token itself and exact it using something like jwt-decode then match the to roles to render different components.

For example you might be doing something like check for a 'admin' role and render a link in nav bar for /admin  route.Which i think i safe to do.
But what if a user looks into your code and sees that there's a /admin route and tries to access it?

So u also got to have logic inside the route to check for role 'admin' and serve something like a '404' if the role doesn't match.

You can dynamically fetch any route once the user role matches.